# Регулярное выражение выбирает лишние символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>New Page</title>
    <script>
        function funMake() {
            //название файла
            var file = '15.jpg';
            //вот здесь по идее регулярное выражение должно выбрать
            //только имя файла без точки и расширения
            //резултьат должен быть 15
            var str = file.match(/(\d*)\.jpg$/);
            //но результать 15.jpg,15 
            document.write(str);
            //почему?
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        funMake();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: По идее .match возвращает массив ["гдея нашел", "что я нашел"]; вот эта строка: //но результат 15.jpg,15 об этом и говорит.

Comment: @Anton121212, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match выдает массив, str[0] - вся строка полностью, str[1] - первый найденный результат

Comment: Что же нужно сделать? Напишите код.

Comment: document.write(str[1]);

Comment: Спасибо! А то пришлось решать этот вопрос с помощью parseInt(str);